# Rstudio is changing my default R Notebook output

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, microbenchmark, rnotebook

I start with a new R Notebook in RStudio:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. Etc Etc Etc.
```

Then I modify it to do what I want -- for example, I'm trying to use `microbenchmark()`.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

Let's compare the sort methods on a set of shuffled integers.

```{r}
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 100000L
microbenchmark(
  sort(sample.int(n),method='radix'),
  sort(sample.int(n),method='quick'),
  sort(sample.int(n),method='shell')
)
```
````

Submitting this `microbenchmark()` to the console gives sensible output, like:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 sort(sample.int(n), method = "radix")  4.685707  4.914925  6.559412  5.619257  7.539383  16.66746   100 a  
 sort(sample.int(n), method = "quick")  8.169732  8.534512 10.490920  9.333782 11.008653  21.44854   100  b 
 sort(sample.int(n), method = "shell") 10.766820 11.144858 15.479061 12.408976 14.519405 133.87898   100   c
```

However, when I try to `knit` it (click the drop-down from "Preview" to "Knit to HTML", it automatically changes my header to:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

Which really messes up the output -- now it looks like this:

[image]

If I go back and change the header back to `output: html_notebook` and click the "Knit" button again, now it looks right:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent RStudio from messing up my first `knit`?

I'm on RStudio Version 1.1.419 for Windows.

Comment: For posterity, I've filed this on the `rmarkdown` repository at https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1469 (since we should likely avoid printing microbenchmark output as paged tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes happening.  First, your `html_notebook` format is being changed to `html_document:`.  Second, the `df_print` option is being added.

Basically the first of these is what `Knit to HTML` is asking for.  `html_document` and `html_notebook` are different formats, and you're asking to change formats.

Once you're in `html_document` format, you probably want `df_print: default` instead of `df_print: paged`. Or you can just leave out the option.

As far as I can see, there's no way to ask for this, other than changing the source of RStudio (around line 118 in this file:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/8af730409bb6d651cc8f6816d136bea91441e7a4/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/rmarkdown/model/RmdTemplateData.java).
That's not very practical for most people.

Of course, after you've got the `html_document` output format chosen, you can change the option (or just delete it).